# How do I block the program / goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a program that fires off two goroutines that provide services in the background. I then want to block the main goroutine and let them run in the background. I want to block 'forever' and I don't care about clean exits. How should I do this? I could wait on channel and then never send anything down it. I could sleep in a loop. Neither feels quite right I thought there might be a simpler `block()` function I could call?

I'm currently doing this

```
var i chan int
<-i
```

Comment: It normally depends on your service implementation. How do you provide those services without blocking (sockets, delays, etc.) ?

Comment: I am `http.ListenAndServe`ing (on different ports) in a number goroutines, depending on configuration. So the main function starts the gorountines, which run in the background. Then my main goroutine has to block, otherwise the program exits. Perhaps I didn't express it clearly in my question.

Comment: I have (possibly) more than one.

Comment: Though the answer given was perfectly good, it might be cleaner for you to simply spawn the first (n - 1) goroutines, and then instead of spawning off the nth, simply call it directly in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, I did think about that, but the tangle of `if`s would be simpler than just calling `select {}` at the end. This is only for a test utility so I think that'll do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) which you pass to each of your goroutine. This is the common way
to wait in the calling goroutine for its children.

However, in your case where you don't care for the results this should do as well:

```
select {}
```

From the [spec regarding `select`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> If there are no cases with non-nil channels, the statement blocks forever

This statement blocks forever while yielding control to the other goroutines.

Comment: Thanks. If the `select` blocks do I need the `for`?

Comment: @Joe No you don't need it, this was a mistake. Corrected it.